# Trying to write an addClock method for a Java assignment

Tags: java

I'm in my first semester learning Java and I'm struggling. For our assignment, we're writing code that is supposed to increment a clock by one second, decrement a clock by one second, and add two clocks together. I *think* I've got the first two sections to work, but I'm having trouble with addClock. Here's what I have so far and I'm just not sure where to go or what's wrong with what I've got:

```
public class Clock
{
    //Instance variables
    private int hours;
    private int minutes;
    private int seconds;
    private int clock;
    private int totalSeconds;

    //Method to convert from totalSeconds to hours, minutes, and seconds
    public void convertSeconds(int totalSeconds)
    {
        hours = (totalSeconds / 3600) % 24;
        minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
        seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    }

    //Method to convert from hours, minutes, and seconds to totalSeconds
    private int getTotalSeconds() 
    {
        int hoursInSeconds = hours * 60 * 60;
        int minutesInSeconds = minutes * 60;
        return hoursInSeconds + minutesInSeconds + seconds;
    }

    //Constructor 1: Initialize time to 0
    public Clock()
    {
        hours = 0;
        minutes = 0;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    //Constructor 2: Value of time in seconds and convert seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds
    public Clock(int totalSeconds)
    {
        convertSeconds(totalSeconds);
    }

    //Constructor 3: Passes three values for hours, minutes, and seconds
    public Clock(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
    {
        hours = hours;
        minutes = minutes;
        seconds = seconds;
    }

    //Instance method tick() to increment a Clock object by one second
    public void tick()
    {
        convertSeconds(getTotalSeconds() + 1);
    }

    //Instance method tickDown() to decrement a Clock object by one second
    public void tickDown()
    {
        convertSeconds(getTotalSeconds() - 1);
    }

    //Accessor/getter method: getHours
    public int getHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    //Accessor/getter method: getMinutes
    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }

    //Accessor/getter method: getSeconds
    public int getSeconds()
    {
        return seconds;
    }

    //Mutator/setter method: setHours
    public void setHours()
    {
        this.hours = hours;
    }

    //Mutator/setter method: setMinutes
    public void setMinutes()
    {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    //Mutator/setter method: setSeconds
    public void setSeconds()
    {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    //Mutator/setter method: setClock
    public void setClock(int totalSeconds)
    {
        this.clock = totalSeconds;
    }

    //Instance method addClock() to give the sum of two clock objects
    public void addClock(Clock clock2)
    {
        convertSeconds(clock2.getTotalSeconds() + this.getTotalSeconds());
    }

    //Main  method to test the functionality of objects
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Clock clock1 = new Clock();
        Clock clock2 = new Clock();

        int clock = 12699;
        int clock2 = 3600;

        clock1.convertSeconds(totalSeconds);
        System.out.println("Number of hours: " + clock1.getHours());
        System.out.println("Number of minutes: " + clock1.getMinutes());
        System.out.println("Number of seconds: " + clock1.getSeconds());

        clock1.tick();
        System.out.println("Number of hours: " + clock1.getHours());
        System.out.println("Number of minutes: " + clock1.getMinutes());
        System.out.println("Number of seconds: " + clock1.getSeconds());

        clock1.tickDown();
        System.out.println("Number of hours: " + clock1.getHours());
        System.out.println("Number of minutes: " + clock1.getMinutes());
        System.out.println("Number of seconds: " + clock1.getSeconds());

        clock1.addClock(clock2);    
        System.out.println("After adding the two clocks, number of hours: " + clock1.getHours());
        System.out.println("After adding the two clocks, number of minutes: " + clock1.getMinutes());
        System.out.println("After adding the two clocks, number of seconds: " + clock1.getSeconds());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, advice, or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please describe your problem in a more concrete way, add error messages or explain what output you are expecting and what you are getting instead.

Comment: The problem is in `convertSeconds()`. You also must do `this.totalSeconds = totalSeconds;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result to `this.totalSeconds`

Answer (score 0):

Does your code compile ?

The error would be here:

```
Clock clock1 = new Clock();
-> Clock clock2 = new Clock();

int clock = 12699;
-> int clock2 = 3600;
```

clock2 is declared 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem comes from the fact that you are storing **two** time's representations: one with `totalSeconds` and one with `hours`, `minutes` and `seconds`. This is rather painful because you have to update one representation when the other get updated.

I recommand instead to store only `totalSeconds`, the 3 others can be inferred based on this one.

It's also a good practice to have only [one main constructor](http://www.yegor256.com/2015/05/28/one-primary-constructor.html), any other constructors must invoke this one. It helps to make your code easier to understand and maintain.

Below is the kind of code you could end with (since it's an assignment, I let you implement the TODOS, if you need them):

```
public final class Clock {
    private int totalSeconds;

    public Clock() {
        this(0);
    }

    public Clock(int hour, int minute, int second) {
        //TODO invoke this(...) with the correct amount of seconds
    }

    public Clock(int totalSeconds) {
        this.totalSeconds = totalSeconds;
    }

    public void addClock(Clock that) {
        this.totalSeconds += that.totalSeconds;
    }

    public void tick() {
        //TODO increment totalSeconds
    }

    public void tickDown() {
        //TODO decrement totalSeconds
    }

    public long getTotalSeconds() {
        return totalSeconds;
    }

    public int getHour() {
        //TODO: compute hour based on totalSeconds
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        //TODO: compute minute based on totalSeconds
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        //TODO: compute second based on totalSeconds
    }   
}
```